# Просьба проверить и подсказать что не так в парочке заданий по Linux

Tags: linux, shell

Есть несколько тестовых вопросов и ответы, которые я написал сам. Как полагаю, если и не верны, хотя бы в ту сторону думаю или нет? Просьба подсказать, заранее благодарен.

1. Linux. Перейдите в домашний каталог и создайте там директорию с именем *test*.

   ```
   cd /home
   mkdir test
   ```

   Верно ли?
2. Создайте файл *script.sh* внутри директории *test*.
   Как через команды создать так и не понял.
3. Linux: Выведите на консоль фразу *Hello, someuser*.

   ```
   echo "Hello, someuser"
   ```

   Так ли?
4. Linux. Некоторая директория содержит каталоги вида *20180201*. Выведите список всех файлов с расширением *log* и их размеры из каталогов, созданных в 2018 году.

   Правильный ли ответ:

   ```
   find /home/20180201 -name "*.log" -mindepth -newermt "2018-01-01" ! -"2018-12-31" -exec ls -sh
   ```

Comment: Домашняя папка - это ~ (cd ~)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. да, правдоподобно. Но можно просто `cd` написать.
2. `touch ~/test/script.sh` или воспользуйтесь любимым редактором
3. можно и так. А можно и `echo "Hello, $USERNAME"`
4. В данном вопросе видимо намекают, что имя каталога совпадает с датой. а значит, можно упростить до `ls 2018*/*.log -sh`. Но я бы тут уточнил у спрашивающего, нужно ли рекурсивно смотреть. В любом случае, есть такой чудный [хелпер для find](http://ru.clihelper.com/find/index.html) который поможет составить команду мышкой.